# how do I run material-ui locally

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to run the material-ui docs locally.  I downloaded the material-ui repository

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/

Did the npm install

Now when I try to run it I get the following error

ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors                                                                                 11:06:22

These dependencies were not found:

- react-jss/lib/contextTypes in ./packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.js
- react-jss/lib/ns in ./packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.js
- recompose/getDisplayName in ./packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.js
- recompose/wrapDisplayName in ./packages/material-ui/src/styles/withTheme.js, ./packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save react-jss/lib/contextTypes react-jss/lib/ns recompose/getDisplayName recompose/wrapDisplayName

As the error states now when I try to run 
npm install --save react-jss/lib/contextTypes react-jss/lib/ns recompose/getDisplayName recompose/wrapDisplayName

I get the following errors

- Asking me access to a repository which I have no access to
- npm ERR! Could not install from "react-jss\lib\contextTypes" as it does not contain a package.json file.

How do I get this running locally?

Answer (score 3):

Material UI uses [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/) to manage dependencies across multiple packages. To install all the dependencies at once, you need to use yarn instead of npm.

If you use `npm`, you need to run `npm install` for each of packages in the `packages/` directory.

For more info, refer to Material-UI's [contributing guidelines](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)

**Requirements**

- Node >= 8.0
- Latest version of Yarn ([how to install/upgrade](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#mac-stable))

#### To run the docs locally

**1.** Clone the repository to your local machine.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui.git
$ cd material-ui
```

**2.** Install dependencies

```
$ yarn
```

**3.** Start the development server

```
$ yarn docs:dev
```

This starts the documentation site in development mode. Making changes to code will hot reload the site.

> If you make changes to TypeScript files in the docs run `yarn docs:typescript --watch` in a separate terminal.

Comment: I tried this and still get  the same error

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors                                 15:22:55


These dependencies were not found:

* react-jss/lib/contextTypes in ./packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.js
* react-jss/lib/ns in ./packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.js
* recompose/getDisplayName in ./packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.js
* recompose/wrapDisplayName in ./packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.js,
./packages/material-ui/src/styles/withTheme.js

Comment: Did you try deleting the node_modules directory, then installing with yarn?

Comment: I get the same errors as you when i install with `npm install.` Removing the node_modules directory, then re-installing with `yarn` should fix it. Let me know if this work for you.

Comment: Hmm... what versions of node / npm / yarn do have installed?

Comment: I upgraded the yarn version and it worked.  I'm a bit confused how this could have caused the issue, and why it wont work if I use npm instead of yarn.

Comment: @tmpdev I just updated my answer again... If you use npm, you need to run `npm install` for each of the packages in the `packages/` directory. See @oliviertassinari's comment at the bottom of [this issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11723)

Answer (score 0):

Material UI documentation is quite huge documentation and is not preferred to launch in the development mode. It is preferred to have a production build and locally host it on your PC.

First, clone the repository.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui.git
cd material-ui
```

Install dependencies using **yarn**.

```sh
yarn
```

Then create a optimized production build of the documentation.

```sh
yarn docs:build
```

Then deploy the build under production.

```sh
yarn docs:start
```

You can find more useful commands by going to the `package.json` file and looking at the `scripts` object.